# Creating a branching QWizard flow

Tags: qt

I'm creating a database-driven Qt application. If the configuration file is missing (first run) then a wizard should run to help the user configure the application. Since database setup is part of this process, I want to give users the ability to create a new database or use an existing one. Being able to use an existing DB is important in case the user exported the database, got a new computer, or reinstalled the program at some point.

However, I noticed that the QWizard object seems to progress in a linear fashion... you go to the next or previous page based on the order in which you add them to the main QWizard object in the code. Basically, at one point I need the user to be taken to Page A if they want to create a new database or Page B if they want to use an existing DB. (and so on). If they choose the option that leads to Page A, the user should never see Page B. (or vice versa)

It's not immediately obvious about how to do this since QWizard seems to want to behave in a completely linear fashion with no branching. I thought about using conditional statements to check which radio button is selected, but that doesn't seem to work during runtime once the Qwizard exec() loop starts.

If this is not possible, being able to re-assemble the next page at runtime based on previous choices would be good enough.

Answer (score 3):

You need to subclass `QWizard` and override `nextId()` to tell it which page to show next.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwizard.html#creating-non-linear-wizards